# css expand toolptip within a range

Tags: html, css, sass

I am using a tooltip which is used to display 2 texts which are :

- Copy Value to Clipboard
- Copied

The expected result is shown below:

[image]
[image]

I tried it using below css

```
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: rem(80px);
  padding: rem(8px) rem(16px);
  border-radius: rem(4px);
  background: var(--white);
  color: var(--gray-900);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  &::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: rem(5px) solid transparent;
    border-right: rem(5px) solid transparent;
    border-top: rem(5px) solid var(--white);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

and this is what I got instead

[image]
[image]

> Need Help: to set a min-width and max-width and let the container expand within this range.

Comment: Can you include a snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Also, have you tried `white-space: nowrap`?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
min-width: max-content
```

or

```
white-space: nowrap
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it fixes the problem, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.